# Schengen Refusal: unable to understand reason

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, visa-refusals

My French Visa was Refused saying "You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence for the duration of intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to admit or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.

The information submitted regarding  the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

what this says I do not understand

Comment: It says, you did not prove sufficiently you have enough money to feed and house yourself while on trip. Of course then the question is, how this could be proven. And that's why I'm voting to close this question as off-topic: we are not immigration lawyers and simply unable to offer relevant advice here.

Comment: @chx There are multiple questions with the same premise and have been answered in this forum. It can be marked as duplicate, but it is a relevant question here.

Comment: @chx, it's on topic, but the question is a duplicate. Please close for that reason

Comment: @chx You seem to be on personal crusade to get rid of visa questions by any means necessary. If you look around, you will see that they are indisputably on topic, useful to many people and well received (in terms of votes, answers…). Ignore them if you don't like them but please respect the other contributors and stop making up rules that do not exist.

Comment: I am not making up rules, I am casting 1 vote, 4 more are necessary. If others don't agree, the question won't be answered. I have answered visa questions in the past, I have nothing against them. There are a lot of pointless (either one off special situations or word-by-word answered in FAQ) questions in this tag, that's all.

Comment: @chx, would you please look at the canonical answer for this question and point out which parts are word-by-word answered in the FAQ? That would be helpful